# Adding a dll to a Website adds a Load of Other dll's?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, .net-assembly

In Visual Studio 2010 have a website project, a class library projects, and a console app.

The class library project talks to YouTube and references dll's Google.GData.Client, Google.GData.Extensions, Google.GData.YouTube etc..

When I add a reference to this project from the console app it just adds the class library dll.

But when I add a reference to the class library project from the website it automatically adds all the google dlls.

Why is this? The console app behaves as I would expect just adding the reference to the class library, but the website adds all the dlls that the class library is dependent on also to the website.

Really I don't want this because I don't want the website to have any knowledge of the underlying framework (youtube). e.g. I don't want developers to be able to create youtube video objects. I have a wrapper class for this so if the underlying video repository changes I won't have to make changes all over the website.

Answer (score 0):

All directly or indirectly dependent assemblies will need to be present in order for your Web application to use your class library.  Your console application, when built, will also have the dependencies in the same folder as the executable.  If you do not want it readily apparent that you use the Google libraries, you will need to [embed them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable) into your class library's assembly.

Another SO question on the topic of dependencies is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265330/net-assembly-dependencies).